# Have 8 out of 10 police officers in Sweden seriously considered quitting due to the danger?

Tags: police, sweden

[This is one source for the claim](http://www.breitbart.com/london/2016/09/20/80-per-cent-swedish-police-consider-quitting-due-danger/).

I know Sweden is having increased delinquence but if this claim is true then the real delinquence is way beyond to what it shows on some statisticss.

I edit to make the question more clear, in the news it states:

> The criminal situation in Sweden may be heading for an even worse turn as a new report has shown that the vast majority of the Swedish police force is so unhappy they are looking into other careers.

With this I think it's clear it refers not to something like "I've had a bad day, I want to quit", but to much more strong consideration of wanting to quit.

Can someone confirm this claim?

Comment: This claim is so very vague, it seems meaningless. 'Considering' seems a low hurdle and doesn't imply they intend to take action.

Comment: I would bet that 10 out of 10 police officers everywhere have considered quitting due to the danger. This hardly seems like a claim at all.

Comment: I think the best approach to this claim would be to say "Here's the survey, here's the methodology" and possibly mention more reliable surveys as an added bonus.

Comment: Not an answer because I have no hard evidence on the claim, but I will note that Breitbart tends to be one of the primary promoters of overblown "Sweden is imploding due to Muslim immigrants" FUD.

Comment: I have never heard about it and I live in Sweden. Also being for instance a construction worker is more dangerous than being a police officer. Breibart is not exactly known for fact checking their stories, but there may be some truth to it. Many police officers have stated that they are unhappy with the recent reorganisation and that salaries are higher in the private sector.

Answer (score 23):

According to a survey 3 of 4 (not quite the same a 8 of 10) police officers are considering changing job. But the main reason stated is that they are unhappy about the salary. Only 7% stated have mentioned threats and violence as a reason.

The reasons for wanting to change job is stated as:

1. Low salary (84%)
2. Unclear leadership (57%)
3. Fuzzy decision making (47%)

Sources:

- ["3 av 4 poliser funderar på att byta jobb"](http://www.svt.se/nyheter/lokalt/ost/3-av-4-poliser-funderar-pa-att-byta-jobb), *SVT.se*
- ["Många poliser vill sluta"](http://www.aftonbladet.se/senastenytt/ttnyheter/inrikes/article22839988.ab), *Aftonbladet*

Comment: If the proportion is 88%, then it could be reported conservatively as either "8 out of 10" or "3 out of 4" by rounding down.